# Bot to Assign Reacting User to a Role in Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a Discord Bot that reads every Emoji Reaction in a Server and assigns the reacting User with a particular role that is specific to the Emoji.

My code should
Assign the Role ***Red*** to Users reacting with  in any message in the server.
Assign the Role ***Blue*** to Users reacting with  in any message in the server.
Assign the Role ***Yellow*** to Users reacting with  in any message in the server.

Here are the IDs of these roles:

```
Red: <@&870162738561814578>
Blue: <@&870162842983206922>
Yellow: <@&870162885412810773>
```

Here's a code snippet of the bot:

```js
const RYellow = '<@&870162885412810773>';
const RBlue = '<@&870162842983206922>';
const RRed = '<@&870162738561814578>';

const RRedEmoji = '';
const RBlueEmoji = '';
const RYellowEmoji = '';

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction) await reaction.fetch();
  if (user.bot) return;
  console.log(reaction);
  if (reaction.emoji.name === RYellowEmoji) {
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RYellow);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RRed);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RBlue);
  }
  if (reaction.emoji.name === RRedEmoji) {
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RRed);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
      .get(user.id)
      .roles.remove(RYellow);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RBlue);
  }
  if (reaction.emoji.name === RBlueEmoji) {
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RBlue);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RRed);
    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
      .get(user.id)
      .roles.remove(RYellow);
  }
});
```

And heres the error:

> E:\Projects\DBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:93
> throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'roles', 'Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes');
> ^
>
> TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or
> Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
> at GuildMemberRoleManager.add (E:\Projects\DBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:93:15)
> at Client. (E:\Projects\DBot\index.js:49:71)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {   [Symbol(code)]:
> 'INVALID_TYPE' }

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<@&870162885412810773>` is not a [snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake) or an ID. You'll need to remove `<@&` and `>`:

```js
const RYellow = '870162885412810773'
const RBlue = '870162842983206922'
const RRed = '870162738561814578'

// ...
```